# How to use skip column name in select query in mysql

Tags: mysql, hide

I want to hide one of the columns on my select query and found out that the skip column name can do it, but what is the correct syntax for that?

Here's my code

```
select t1.location, MAX(DATE_ADD((FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.t_stamp/1000)),INTERVAL 4 HOUR) AS Tstamp,

  max(case when t2.locationid = '2847' then t2.value end) MR,
  max(case when t2.locationid = '2839' then t2.value end) Flow,
  max(case when t2.locationid = '2834' then t2.value end) Pressure,
  max(case when t2.locationid = '2836' then t2.value end) Level

from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1
  on t1.id = '2847'
group by t1.location
```

so on the output i have the columns with the latest value,

```
Location |        Tstamp        | MR | Flow | Pressure | Level
   East  |  2013-11-10 12:00 PM | 10 |  20  |   30     |   40
```

four hours ago

```
Location |        Tstamp        | MR | Flow | Pressure | Level
   East  |  2013-11-10 08:00 AM | 20 |  25  |   34     |   45
```

and what I want to happen is for it to be just:

```
Location | MR | Flow | Pressure | Level
   East  | 20 |  25  |   34     |   45
```

If i remove the t_stamp from the select query, how can I still show the values four hours ago?

Comment: If you don't want the field, why select it in the first place, especially when it's forcing the DB to waste its time doing a bunch of date math that is just going to be thrown away

Comment: @viakondratiuk I tried it like this -MAX(DATE_ADD((FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.t_stamp/1000)),INTERVAL 4 HOUR) and --MAX(DATE_ADD((FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.t_stamp/1000)),INTERVAL 4 HOUR)

Comment: Not selecting is the right syntax

Comment: @MarcB I can't remove it cause I need it too

Comment: @kostyan i need it to show the values for the past 4 hours but i don't need that column to show, how else can i do that without selecting it? is there a diff way?

Comment: you're not using Tstamp to filter results, putting it in select alone does nothing

Comment: Please show example data, expected output and your column data types. Otherwise this is just guessing.

Comment: @juergend ok how about that? i edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.location,
  max(case when t2.locationid = '2847' then t2.value end) MR,
  max(case when t2.locationid = '2839' then t2.value end) Flow,
  max(case when t2.locationid = '2834' then t2.value end) Pressure,
  max(case when t2.locationid = '2836' then t2.value end) Level
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 on t1.id = '2847'
where now() - INTERVAL 4 HOUR >= FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.t_stamp/1000) 
group by t1.location
```

Comment: I can't just remove it cause I need it to show the value for the past 4 hours

Comment: You don't need it selected. Where do you need it? In the `where` clause?

Comment: I tried doing it the where clause and did WHERE MAX(DATE_ADD((FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.t_stamp/1000)),INTERVAL 4 HOUR) but i got an error. how's the right way if i want to just put it on the where clause?

Comment: i got an error " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use"